How to implement multi-role user authorization in Blazor Web App?
I have designed database tables as following:
Users:



Id
Name
Username
Password




1
Alex
al2024
******



Roles:



Id
Role




1
Administrator


2
User



UserRoles:



Id
UserRef
RoleRef




1
1
1


2
1
2



I use the following code to set roles after user authentication:
var userRoles = await _dbContext.UserRoles.Where(x => x.UserRef = 1);

var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, Model.Username),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, string.Join(",", userRoles))
};

var Identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(Identity);
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);

I use @attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")] in my component.
After that I don't know what to do.
The component accepts only Administrator while I have Administrator,User in the user role claim.

I believe that setting the Role Claim to "Administrator,User" means that a user is only authorized to see those components marked as [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator,User")] In other words, the string is considered the name of the role, not split on commas. I think you'd need to add two Claims of type ClaimTypes.Role with each role name, to the list.

@HereticMonkey Did you mean new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, string.Join(",", userRoles[0])) and new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, string.Join(",", userRoles[1]))?

@HereticMonkey Can we add ClaimTypes.Role two times?

@HereticMonkey Thank you. It worked. Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it as correct answer.

I don't think you'd want string.Join("," in there if you're only adding one item, and as far as I know, there's no restriction on the claims added, but I've been wrong before and will be again. I'm guessing here (hence why I used a comment and not an answer).

@HereticMonkey I know. The problem solved.

I believe that setting the Role Claim to "Administrator,User" means that a user is only authorized to see those components marked as [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator,User")] In other words, the string is considered the name of the role, not split on commas. I think you'd need to add two Claims of type ClaimTypes.Role with each role name, to the list. Something like the following should work:
var userRoles = await _dbContext.UserRoles.Where(x => x.UserRef = 1);

var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, Model.Username)
};
claims.AddRange(userRoles.Select(ur => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, ur.Role)));

var Identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(Identity);
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);

